# Android JNI undefined reference to error c++ methods

Tags: android, c++, cmake, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I am trying to call methods from AVS SDK using Android JNI.
The source code is in C++. 
but while building the apk i am facing the following error.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:externalNativeBuildDebug'.
Build command failed.
Error while executing process /home/useradm/Androidsdk/cmake/3.10.2.4988404/bin/cmake with arguments {--build /root/AndroidStudioProjects/alexaProtoApp/app/.externalNativeBuild/cmake/debug/x86 --target native-lib}
[1/2] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/native-lib.cpp.o
[2/2] Linking CXX shared library /root/AndroidStudioProjects/alexaProtoApp/app/build/intermediates/cmake/debug/obj/x86/libnative-lib.so
FAILED: /root/AndroidStudioProjects/alexaProtoApp/app/build/intermediates/cmake/debug/obj/x86/libnative-lib.so 
: && /home/useradm/Androidsdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang++ --target=i686-none-linux-android24 --gcc-toolchain=/home/useradm/Androidsdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64 --sysroot=/home/useradm/Androidsdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot -fPIC -g -DANDROID -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -fno-addrsig -Wa,--noexecstack -Wformat -Werror=format-security   -O0 -fno-limit-debug-info  -Wl,--exclude-libs,libgcc.a -Wl,--exclude-libs,libatomic.a -static-libstdc++ -Wl,--build-id -Wl,--warn-shared-textrel -Wl,--fatal-warnings -Wl,--no-undefined -Qunused-arguments -Wl,-z,noexecstack -shared -Wl,-soname,libnative-lib.so -o /root/AndroidStudioProjects/alexaProtoApp/app/build/intermediates/cmake/debug/obj/x86/libnative-lib.so CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/native-lib.cpp.o  /root/AndroidStudioProjects/alexaProtoApp/app/src/main/cpp/../../main/jniLibs/x86/libSampleApp.so /home/useradm/Androidsdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/i686-linux-android/24/liblog.so /home/useradm/Androidsdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/i686-linux-android/24/liblog.so -latomic -lm && :
/root/AndroidStudioProjects/alexaProtoApp/app/src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp:25: error: undefined reference to 'my_initialize(_JavaVM*, _jobject*)'
clang++: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

Here is my

**native-lib.cpp**

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <ostream>
#include "custom_main.h"
#include <android/log.h>

JavaVM *my_jvm;
jobject activity;

extern "C"
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL
Java_myapp_avs_activities_MainActivity_initialize(JNIEnv *env, jobject instance) {

activity = env->NewGlobalRef(instance);
return my_initialize(my_jvm, activity);


}extern "C"
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL JNI_OnLoad(JavaVM *vm, void *aReserved) {

my_jvm = vm;
if (vm != NULL)
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "AVSapp", "Assigned");
return JNI_VERSION_1_6;

}extern "C"
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL JNI_OnUnload(JavaVM *vm, void *reserved) {
   __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "AVSapp", "OnUnload");
}
```

**custom_main.h**

```
#ifndef CUSTOM_MAIN_H
#define CUSTOM_MAIN_H
#include "jni.h"

int my_initialize(JavaVM *, jobject);

#endif
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "custom_main.h"
int my_initialize(JavaVM* myJavaVM, jobject instance) {

}
```

Note : Due to restrictions i am not be able to share the full code , hence shared snippet.

My question is , is this linker related issue ? , Please guide me solving this issue.

Comment: I see you building with `native-lib.cpp`, but not with `main.cpp`. You need to add it to your project or build system.

Comment: native-lib.cpp resides in my Android Project. 
where as main.cpp resides in the sdk which is i am implementing in my android project.

my cmake list and other files are properly written. there are other methods in main.cpp ( i havent shown here) which doesn't have undefined reference error but only this method is getting the error.

Comment: Maybe you should put the `my_initialize` function in a separate source file that can be used from both projects?

Comment: i have copied the header file in my android project and also have included in native-lib.cpp , so that i can get the reference of the method. 
i have also copied the so files in jniLibs folder according to the platform.

Comment: add `#include "custom_main.h"` to main.cpp

Comment: @APP : it was already present , question edited.

Comment: have you tried this option, from android studio click on Build->Refresh linked c++ project and again rebuild your project

Comment: @APP : i tried this, i also tried deleting the build folder which was being generated by compiling. Do i have to use extern "C" at my methods , is the error related to this ??

Comment: add `#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif` at the beggining of custom_main.h and 
`#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif` at the end

Comment: @KarmaCoding Have you check?

Comment: @APP: sorry for the late reply , i solved this error by removing everything and compiling it from scratch , but i still have no idea why it was not working.

Answer (score 1):

use extern c in custom_main.h, it will work

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

#ifndef CUSTOM_MAIN_H
#define CUSTOM_MAIN_H
#include "jni.h"

int my_initialize(JavaVM *, jobject);

#endif

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

Build->Refresh linked c++ project and again rebuild your project